# Return a byte[] array from controller class in ASP.NET

Tags: c#, arrays, json, byte

I have a Controller class (in `C#`) which has to return a byte array from its login method. Please find the below source code of my Controller class for my Login functionality.

```
[RoutePrefix("Account")]
    public class AccountsController : ApiController     
    {
        [Route("Login")]
        [HttpPost]   
        public byte[] Login()
        {
            byte[] mSessionID = new Session().getmSessionID();
            return mSessionID;
        }
    }
```

While Testing, the web service returns a base64Encoded string value as "`LVpgqWBYkyXX1FlDg95vlA==`". I want my Web service to return a byte array response (which is in JSON response).

Comment: It looks like you are using ASP.NET 5 WebApi or lower. Correct? By default, WebAPI returns byte[] as Base64-encoded. You can change how the response is returned, but how do you want to see the information? Should it be an array of hex values in a JSON object? Or should it be an octet-stream response? Please provide an example of what you want your API to return.

Comment: I am not aware of both formats. But the format I would want to should look as given below: {Numbers : 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 1, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15,2,45 }; . I want the web service to return a byte array itself

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to get the response in this format:

```
{
  "Numbers": [
    2,
    3,
    4,
    5,
    6,
    7,
    8,
    9,
    10,
    1,
    11,
    12,
    13,
    14,
    15,
    2,
    45
  ]
}
```

**Solution 1: JSON Formatters**

You need to modify the way that JSON is serialized. WebAPI uses JSON.Net unser the hood to format WebAPI responses as JSON. We can override the byte[] formatter as follows:

Create a custom formatter

```
public class ByteArrayFormatter : JsonConverter
{
    public override bool CanConvert(Type objectType)
    {
        return objectType == typeof(byte[]);
    }
    public override bool CanRead
    {
        get
        {
            return false;
        }
    }
    public override bool CanWrite
    {
        get
        {
            return true;
        }
    }
    public override void WriteJson(JsonWriter writer, object value, JsonSerializer serializer)
    {
        var byteArray = (byte[])value;
        writer.WriteStartArray();
        if (byteArray != null && byteArray.Length > 0)
        {
            foreach (var b in byteArray)
            {
                writer.WriteValue(b);
            }
        }
        writer.WriteEndArray();
    }
    public override object ReadJson(JsonReader reader, Type objectType, object existingValue, JsonSerializer serializer)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

Register the formatter globally in the `Application_Start` method in `Global.asax.cs` (note that ALL `byte[]` types will be serialised this way):

```
var formatters = GlobalConfiguration.Configuration.Formatters;
var jsonFormatter = formatters.JsonFormatter;
jsonFormatter.SerializerSettings.Converters.Add(new ByteArrayFormatter());
```

Create a model so that your JSON response has a `Numbers` property:

```
public class NumbersModelByte
{
    public byte[] Numbers { get; set; }
}
```

Modify your controller to use this model:

```
[Route("login")]
[System.Web.Http.AcceptVerbs("GET")]
[System.Web.Http.HttpGet]
public NumbersModelByte Login()
{
    byte[] mSessionID = new Session().getmSessionID();
    return new NumbersModelByte
    {
        Numbers = mSessionID
    };
}
```

**Solution 2: The quick and dirty**

You will need to return an object (a model).

NumbersModelInt.cs (notice the int[] type)

```
public class NumbersModelInt
{
    public int[] Numbers { get; set; }
}
```

Then you need to cast all of your bytes in your byte array to ints in the response:

```
[Route("Login")]
[HttpPost]   
public byte[] Login()
{
    byte[] mSessionID = new Session().getmSessionID();
    return new NumbersModelInt
    {
        Numbers = mSessionID.Select(b => (int) b).ToArray()
    };
}
```

Comment: No problem. Let me know how it goes

Comment: Thanks Joao.. I tried the first option and it works perfectly fine.. Thank you so much.. I was struggling with this for a while and got a clearer idea on how to implement things in C# (I am new to it).. Cheers...

Comment: No worries. Glad to have been able to help

Answer (score 0):

Answering my second question. (Passing a JSON Object into method of Controller)

I got help from my colleague, and she was able to find a proper link.

https://weblog.west-wind.com/posts/2013/dec/13/accepting-raw-request-body-content-with-aspnet-web-api....

The code changes I made to fix the issue are

public async Task Login()
        {
            string input = await Request.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();            dynamic data = Newtonsoft.Json.Linq.JObject.Parse(input); 
        }

(input -returns as a string in in JSON  format)
(data - returns the JSON Object)

Comment: Can I return a sbyte[] from ByteArrayFormatter.cs in CanConvert method