# Returning a byte array from a GET call on ASP.NET API

Tags: c#, api, asp.net-core-3.1

I have been trying to recreate an existing API for testing purposes.
Original API is returning a XML presented as an array of bytes.

I have already modeled my GET response XML to look like the original and am now trying to display it as a byte array but the problem I am encountering is while calling my API from Postman the result is a Base64Encoded string.

My GET method is reading rows from an SQL table via Dapper into a model I made.

My current code:

```
    //[Produces("application/xml")]
    [ApiController]
    [Route("[controller]")]
    public class UserController : ControllerBase
    {
        [Route("{employeeID?}")]
        [HttpGet]
        public byte[] Get(int? employeeID = null)
        {
            using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(_connectionString))
            {
                con.Open();

                employees = con.Query<Employee, EmploymentData, Employee>(query, (emp, empData) => {
                    emp.EmploymentData = empData;
                    return emp;
                }, splitOn: "CompanyID");
            }

            GetResponse response = new GetResponse()
            {
                Employees = (List<Employee>)employees,
                ErrorCode = null,
                ErrorMessage = null,
                InputParameterErrors = null,
                ResultInfo = new ResultInfo()
                {
                    ResultDateTime = DateTime.Now,
                    EmployeeCount = employees.Count()
                }
            };

            byte[] bytes = ObjectToByteArray(response);
            return bytes;
        }

        public static byte[] ObjectToByteArray(Object obj)
        {
            BinaryFormatter bf = new BinaryFormatter();
            using (var ms = new MemoryStream())
            {
                bf.Serialize(ms, obj);
                return ms.ToArray();
            }
        }
```

I have already tried [Produces("application/octet-stream")] instead of application/xml but I get 406 Not Acceptable in Postman.

Comment: XML is text, not bytes. There's no if or but or "in my case"

Comment: This should answer your question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38949045/return-a-byte-array-from-controller-class-in-asp-net and, about Postman, make sure that you're setting correct Accept value in header in postman itself. The header may be "Hidden", so make sure you chose to display auto-generated headers.